# Capistrano - Ruby on Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, rvm, capistrano, puma

I have a very simple ruby on rails application and I want to use capistrano to deploy it.

It took me some time to configure the project and deploy the application and I'm not sure I made it right.

There are multiple gems in the gemfile, ok. When I run `gem list puma` in the server it returns null, which means that the gem 'puma' is not installed in the server, right?

but I've just deployed the application via capistrano, shouldn't all the gems in the gemfile be properly installed?

and then I thought: is capistrano supposed to install gems in the deploy?

My application is simple and I'm spending way more time to deploy and launch it than I should. Is it so complex to deploy and ruby on rails app?

Answer (score 1):

Go to your current directory of your application folder and try running the command with bundle exec.

Comment: what is the difference between `gem list puma` and `bundle exec gem list puma`?

Comment: gem list makes you interact with the rubygems that are being used by ruby by default. Whereas in your rails application Bundler manages the gems, so when you do **bundle exec gem list puma** it doesnot interact with rubygems, it interacts on the basis of your Gemfile. Thus showing you the results for the gem that are being used in your application.